# Whats the difference between this 2 flowing code with same objective

Tags: c++, arrays

**Question:**
Starting with a 1-indexed array of size `n` filled with all zeroes, you are required to perform the following operation `m` times:

> Each operation contains 3 integers `a`, `b` and `k`. You are required to add `k` to the value at all the indices from `a` to `b` (both inclusive).

Once all operations have been performed, return the maximum value in the array.

**Input Format:**
The first line contains two space-separated integers `n` and `m`, the size of the array and the number of operations respectively.
Each of the next `m` lines contains three space-separated integers `a`, `b` and `k`, the left index, right index and integer to add respectively.

**Constraints:**

```
1 <= n, m <= 10^5
1 <= a <= b <= n
-10^9 <= k <= 10^9
```

**Examples:**

```
Sample Input 1:
10 3
1 5 3
4 8 7
6 9 1

Sample Output 1:
10

Explanation:
Given n = 10 and m = 3

Queries are interpreted as follows:
a b k
1 5 3
4 8 7
6 9 1

Add the values of k between the indices a and b inclusive:

     1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 (index)

    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] (Initially)

    [3,3,3,3,3,0,0,0,0,0] (After Query 1)

    [3,3,3,10,10,7,7,7,0,0] (After Query 2)

    [3,3,3,10,10,8,8,8,1,0] (After Query 3)

The largest value is 10 after all operations are performed.
```

```
Sample Input 2:

5 3
1 2 100
2 5 100
3 4 100

Sample Output:
200

Explanation:
After the first update the list is 100 100 0 0 0.
After the second update list is 100 200 100 100 100.
After the third update list is 100 200 200 200 100.

The maximum value is 200.
```

This code ran and gave the correct output:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int n, m;
  cin >> n >> m;

  vector<long long int> arr(n, 0);

  for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    int start, finish, value;
    cin >> start >> finish >> value;
    arr[start - 1] += value;
    arr[finish] -= value;
  }

  long long int ans = 0;
  long long int current = 0;

  for (int value : arr) {
    current += value;
    if (current > ans) {
      ans = current;
    }
  }

  cout << ans;

  return 0;
}
```

but this code is giving me segment fault:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    long long int n,m;
    cin>>n>>m;
    long long int x[n] ={0};
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        long long int a,b,k;
        cin>>a>>b>>k;
        x[a-1] += k;
        if(b<n)
           x[b] -= k;
    }
    long long int max=0,current=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        current=x[i]+current;
        if(max<current)
            max=current;
    }
    cout<<max<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please do not use both C and C++ tags. These are two different languages. Pick the one you really need. Edit your question to remove the bad one.

Comment: @RAHUL MITTAL There is much common in the programs. At least the both programs are very and very bad.:)

Comment: The 2nd example isn't valid c++ code.

Comment: `long long int x[n] ={0};` is non-standard and you will need to check your compiler documentation to see if it does zero the whole array, just the 1st element, or something else entirely. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ except for the header tag can you please state what's invalid it could be the problem with my code 

Comment: @RichardCritten ya it assigns 0 to all the elements of the array I tried it by printing the array after declaring it and I will make sure not to use this next time as its a non standerd

Comment: @RAHUL MITTAL Why are you using the expression for index  start - 1 (arr[start - 1]) but the expression finish  instead of finish - 1 (arr[finish] )? This does not make a sense.

Comment: @RAHUL MITTAL Moreover the code does not correspond to the description.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow the for loop run from arr[start-1] till arr[finish] instead of arr[finish -1] as I want till arr[finish-1] the value is added but not in arr[finish] so I have assigned a negative value at arr[finish] you can try running the sample input you might understand

Comment: @RAHULMITTAL This does not make any sense.

Comment: @RAHULMITTAL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem in your code is in the line `x[b] -= k;`

Since `b` is `1`-indexed, this means that `b` can be upto `n` but your array of size `n` has indices from `0` to `n-1` and if there is a query where `b = n`, then you get segmentation fault.

You can correct this by placing an `if` condition just before this line like this:
`if (b < n)`

Also, in the first code, you should have encountered the same problem but somehow your compiler overlooked the indexing problem in vector.

Comment: Thanks, bro you found an issue but it's still showing me segment fault.

Comment: @RAHULMITTAL On my machine, its working perfectly fine now. Try running it on some online compiler like ideone.com

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/crush/copy-from/214906404 Please try in this sample cases it works for small input but for large it doesn't

Comment: @RAHULMITTAL This solution got accepted. Here is the [code](https://ideone.com/4KNTnZ). In this code I have used some `#define` templates to write faster code. Plz let me know if you don't understand it.

Comment: @RAHULMITTAL You can consider upvoting and accepting my answer if it helped you :)

Comment: @risingStark If you can not reproduce then your answer does not make a sense.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I reproduced the error, then corrected it. He gave me the problem link to submit the answer, I submitted in that as well and got accepted.

Comment: thanks, @risingStark but my question is what's the mistake in the above code

Comment: @RAHULMITTAL That's what I told you. There is no mistake other than the one I pointed out in the answer. I got my solution accepted so it means that it is working on hackerrank judge perfectly fine